# Gatsby not adding className to html element after gatsby build

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, material-ui, gatsby

I am new to Gatsby and this is my first time building a website with gatsby and react. When I run gatsby develop command, everything looks fine. All the CSS classes are loaded.

[image: This picture is from the inspect element after I run gatsby develop]

And the output is like this:

[image]

However, after I run the gatsby build command and then run gatsby serve, the class="static-websites" is not added to 2 paragraphs and the output looks different.

A photo from the inspect element after gatsby build and serve

[image]

Output after gatsby build and serve

[image]

Here's the basic code

[image]

1. I have removed the svg code to make it look clean.
2. This entire exact same p tag is repeated 5 times inside the Paper.

Note: I commented out the second p tag and then the class got removed from the sample website 3 paragraph. So the class="static-website" is being removed from alternate p tags.
It is working fine in gatsby develop though. Also, I am using material-ui.

Not a browser issue as I have tried in the new Edge, firefox and chrome.
New to gatsby so any help is appreciated.

Comment: definitely would be of much help if you add the code where and how you are writing those parts of html, gatsby can generate html from a lot of sources

Comment: Got it! Adding in 5 minutes.

Comment: @diedu done! Thanks for letting me know that. I read somewhere that it might be because of gatsby-plugin-purgecss. Any thoughts on that?

Comment: did you add the material ui plugin? https://www.gatsbyjs.org/packages/gatsby-plugin-material-ui/

Comment: No I didn't before. The whole site was working fine except these 2 paragraphs. Now I have added it and still the same issue.

Comment: I found some issues in the gatsby repo related to different output in the build, seems it has to do with ssr, I suggest to ask this directly in a issue in the github repo, just make sure to have a little repo replicating this problem and I think adding the output from running `gatsby info` would help too

Comment: Yeah I tried adding some stuff to the gatsby-ssr.js file but it didn't work. I have just wrapped these p tags in another div to make it work for now. Thank for the help! @diedu